# JMeter XML Schema validation stopped at first error

Tags: jmeter, data-validation, xml-file

I am using XML schema validation to validate XML response against XSD schema.
Problem is that XML validation is stopped after first error found.

For example, i have one error at line 105 and second at line 1200
It returns only error at line 105, then i have to fix this, or add value to XSD schema, only then i can see error at line 1200.

Is it possible to see all errors in one report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schema Assertion uses [javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method which stops parsing XML file after the first error.

You can work it around by implementing your own [ErrorHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) in i.e. [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion)

1. Add Beanshell Assertion instead of the XML Schema Assertion
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell Assertion "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
   import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
   import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

   import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
   import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
   import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
   import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
   import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.util.LinkedList;
   import java.util.List;


   SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
   Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("/path/to/your/schema.xsd")));
   Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
   final List exceptions = new LinkedList();
   validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

       public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
           exceptions.add(exception);
       }

       public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
           exceptions.add(exception);
       }

       public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
           exceptions.add(exception);
       }
   });
   StreamSource xmlFile = new StreamSource(new StringReader(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString()));
   validator.validate(xmlFile);

   if (exceptions.size() > 0) {
       Failure = true;
       for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.size(); i++) {
           FailureMessage += "Error " + (i + 1) + " : " + exceptions.get(i).getMessage();
           FailureMessage += System.getProperty("line.separator");

       }
   }
   ```
3. Replace `/path/to/your/schema.xsd` with the actual path to XSD schema.

Remember that it may NOT return all the errors in case of **fatal** errors, according to ErrorHandler class JavaDoc:

> Note, however, that there is no requirement that the parser continue to report additional errors after a call to fatalError. In other words, a SAX driver class may throw an exception after reporting any fatalError.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java API in Beanshell Test Elements.

Comment: i am receiving following error: BeanShell Assertion : org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler; import org.xml.sax.SAXException; import org.xml . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Final variable, can't re-assign.